# Django Model Subclass - no fields declared in subclass creating indentation error

Tags: python, django

```
class Value_List:
    name = models.charfield(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=140)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Meter(Value_List):


class ContributionRole(Value_List):


class AttributionCertainty(Value_List):
```

The subclasses don't need their own fields declared (Value_List is for Option lists of various sorts).

This is causing an indentation error at `class Meter(Value_List)`, because there is no indented block beneath it.

Comment: just add `pass` to every class? Not sure if that actually works though :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like shmee said, you need "pass" to avoid the indentation error

```
class Meter(Value_List):
    pass
```